# Regex Expression in R to match a word with only non-word characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

Trying to remove all words(characters surrounded by a whitespace) that contain only non-word characters or only punctuation.

```
**My string:**  df <-c("****+++++01293-0129-= *& ==============( ----------------( hi 102938=-0 123ho123")


**Intended output:"****+++++01293-0129-= hi 102938=-0 123ho123"
```

Tried:

```
df <- gsub(pattern = "[[:punct:]]*span[[:punct:]]*", "", df)

df <-gsub(pattern = "\\<\\W*\\W*\\>", "", df)

df <-gsub(pattern = "^\\W*\\W*$", "", df)
```

None of these work for removing each word that contains purely punctuation characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try searching for the pattern:

```
(?<=^|\s)[^A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=$|\s)
```

and then replace with empty string.  For example:

```
input <-c("****+++++01293-0129-= *& ==============( ----------------( hi 102938=-0 123ho123")
output <- gsub("(?<=^|\\s)[^A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=$|\\s)", "", input, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "****+++++01293-0129-=  hi 102938=-0 123ho123"
```

The secret sauce in the regex pattern is the use of lookarounds as proxies for what we would normally do using word boundaries (`\b`).  This issue here is that the interface between a *non* word character and a space isn't actually a word boundary.  So instead, we can define our boundaries as being an interface between a non word character and one of the following:

- The start of the string
- The end of the string
- A space character

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest but this should work

```
paste(grep("[[:alnum:]]",strsplit(df," ")[[1]],value=TRUE),collapse=" ")
[1] "****+++++01293-0129-= hi 102938=-0 123ho123"
```

Here we are splitting the string by `" "` and checking if there is at least one alphanumeric value. Those that do are then pasted again with `" "` as separator.

Comment: Good answer that doesnt use PCRE regular expressions library but R syntax, for those who are not familiar with PCRE.